# How can you change the default ScrollPhysics in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to change the `ScrollPhysics` for almost every scrollable widget in an app to `BouncingScrollPhysics()`. I have tried to find a way to do this without adding the `physics` property everywhere, but I haven't found good a way yet. One solution is to use [flutter_platform_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets) and set `initialPlatform` to iOS, but that will change a lot of other things as well.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and in that case how?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can extend `ScrollBehavior` and put in `builder` of `MaterialApp`
In demo code, `iOS, macOS, android` will use `BouncingScrollPhysics` 
code snippet

```
class ScrollBehaviorModified extends ScrollBehavior {
  const ScrollBehaviorModified();
  @override
  ScrollPhysics getScrollPhysics(BuildContext context) {
    switch (getPlatform(context)) {
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
      case TargetPlatform.android:
        return const BouncingScrollPhysics();
      case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        return const ClampingScrollPhysics();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
...
builder: (context, widget) {
        return ScrollConfiguration(
            behavior: ScrollBehaviorModified(), child: widget);
      },
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class ScrollBehaviorModified extends ScrollBehavior {
  const ScrollBehaviorModified();
  @override
  ScrollPhysics getScrollPhysics(BuildContext context) {
    switch (getPlatform(context)) {
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
      case TargetPlatform.android:
        return const BouncingScrollPhysics();
      case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        return const ClampingScrollPhysics();
    }
    return null;
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      builder: (context, widget) {
        return ScrollConfiguration(
            behavior: ScrollBehaviorModified(), child: widget);
      },
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.separated(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Text('Item$index');
                },
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Divider();
                },
                itemCount: 50,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: with this ClampingScrollPhysics does not follow ThemeData, how to fix this?

Answer (score 10):

Another solution without a new class :

```dart
MaterialApp(
  scrollBehavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
      parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    ),
  ),
  // ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

simple solution for your particular question is =>
inside ThemeData

```
platform: TargetPlatform.iOS,
```

[Snapshot of the Theme code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnUI7.png)

Comment: Just a note on this, it will work, but it also changes other things that you might not want, such as the default page transition animation too.