# How to set the default Scroll Physics of an android flutter app

Tags: flutter, listview

I am developing a flutter app, and simply want to change the default scrolling physics to BouncingScrollPhysics so my listviews are more modified.

I know that there is already an answered question but it doesn't work on the latest version of flutter.

I wouldn't want to go around my app changing ListView properties an doing bad practices, any help would be appreciated <3

Comment: This will help you: [Default ScrollPhysics in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62809540/how-can-you-change-the-default-scrollphysics-in-flutter)

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work!

Comment: `MaterialApp(
  scrollBehavior: MyScrollBehavior(),
  // ...
);` Can you try doing it this way?

Comment: Thank you very much! That actually works, I hope you leave it as an answer in case anyone faces the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to this solution:
[Default ScrollPhysics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62810356/15285043)

```dart
class MyScrollBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  const MyScrollBehavior();
  @override
  ScrollPhysics getScrollPhysics(BuildContext context) => const BouncingScrollPhysics();
}
```

```dart
MaterialApp(
  scrollBehavior: MyScrollBehavior(),
  // ...
);
```